# Exercise 4 from Remmert

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I'm doing Complex Analysis using Theory of Complex Functions, by Remmert. The exercise 0.1.4 states:

a) Show that from $(1+|v|^2)u=(1+|u|^2)v$, $u,v \in \mathbb{C}$, it follows that either $u=v$ or $\overline{u}v=1$.

My attempt:

$\frac{u}{v}=\frac{1+|u|^2}{1+|v|^2}$

So it follows that $u=kv$ for some $k\in \mathbb{R}$. Using this I can rewrite the original ecuation:

$(1+|v|^2)kv=(1+|kv|^2)v$

$kv+kv|v|^2=v+v|kv|^2$

$kv-v|kv|^2=v-kv|v|^2$

$kv-vk^2|v|^2=v-kv|v|^2$

$kv(1-k|v|^2)=v(1-k|v|^2)$

So it follows that $k$ must be $1$ and it implies $u=v$

Is that Ok? Anyway, I can't see when the second option must hold. Can you help me, please?

Comment: What about the case $1-k|v|^2=0$?

Comment: Thanks, don't know how I couldn't realized It before....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does not follow that $k=1$. Either $k=1$ or $k|v|^2=1$, from which it follows that $u\bar v =1$. (By the way, you can eliminate the case $u=v=0$ at the beginning and divide out a $v$ to make life simpler.)